# Записать два вектора поочередно, поэлементно в файл. С++

Tags: c++, vector

Есть два вектора.
Задача записать их в бинарный файл.
Только сначала первые 3 элемента с первого вектора, затем первые 4 из второго, и так далее.
Допустим

```
 std::vector<int> v1 = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };
 std::vector<int> v2 = { 11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23 };
И перед каждой записью пишу индекс.

Должна получится строка: **1** 1 2 3 11 12 13 14 **2** 4 5 6 15 16 17 18 **3** 7 8 9 19 20 21 22 23

int n = 3;
int writev1 = 3;
int writev2 = 4;
for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i ++){
     int index = i  + 1; 
     file.write((char *)&index, sizeof(int));

     for (size_t j = 0; j < writev1; ???){  // какое должно быть условие      
     file.write((char*)&v1[j], sizeof(int));
}
 for (size_t k = 0; k < writev2; ???){  // какое должно быть условие      
     file.write((char*)&v2[j], sizeof(int));
}
```

Comment: Читать http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Comment: `j < 3` и `k < 4` соответственно (во втором цикле опечатка - используется j в `file.write((char*)&v2[j], sizeof(int));` вместо `k`. Этим обеспечите запись по 3 и 4 значения из массивов. А в качестве индексов (чтобы не проходить по одним и тем же элементам) используйте отдельные переменные, которые увеличивайте в цикле. (либо вне циклов сразу на 3 и 4, а в цикле складывайте с переменными цикла).

Comment: j < 3 и k < 4. Нет, пройдем раз, запишем с 1го по 3й элемент, потом идем второй раз, и запишется снова тоже самое, а должно уже идти с 4го элемента

Comment: Можно использовать отдельные переменные, которые будут увеличиваться в циклах (как вариант итераторы, примерно так: https://repl.it/@vladimirgamalian/ElectricIntentionalWorkspace)

Comment: @Vladimir Gamalyan, спасибо! с вектором int работает, а с   std::vector<short> v1;  auto i1 = v1.begin() - не определяется

Answer (score 0):

Класс valarray лучший кандидат: (если не знакомы, то рекомендую изучать)

```
std::vector<int> v1{ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, 10 };
std::vector<int> v2{ 11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23 };
// инициализируем обьекты valarray содержанием векторов   
std::valarray<int> val1(&v1[0], v1.size()), 
                   val2(&v2[0], v2.size());     
const int w1 = 3, w2 = 4,
        k = val1.size()/w1,
        sum = w1 + w2,
        sz = k * sum;
std::valarray<int> val3(sz);
// теперь с помощью срезов инициализируем val3 так, как требует задача
for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
    val3[slice(i * sum, w1, 1)] = val1[slice(i * w1, w1, 1)];
    val3[slice(w1 + i * sum, w2, 1)] = val2[slice((i * w2), w2, 1)];
} 
// записываем содержание val3 в файл вместе с дополнительной информацией 
for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
    file << " **" << i + 1 << "** " ;
    for(int j = i * sum; j < i * sum + sum; ++j) {
        file << val3[j] << ' ';
    }
}
```